# Handle next parameter with no @login_required

Tags: python, flask

A user is at a page with comments. If they are already looged in, then they may add their own comment. If not, then there is a link to the login page. 
After they have logged in I would like to take the user back to the before-login page.

I have tried

```
<a href="{{url_for('login', next = url_for('product_details', product=prod.id)')}}" role="button">Login</a>
```

with

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        #login the user...
        if request.args.get('next'):
            return redirect(request.args.get('next'))
        else:
            # proceed as usual...
```

This does not work. For one thing, `request.args.get('next')` is gone after `form.validate_on_submit()`.  Besides this, my approach feels wrong.  What is the correct way to redirect from a `next` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

You could put the "next" parameter in a session, and then pop that value from the session after the user logs in.

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():

    if request.args.get('next'):
        session['next_url'] = request.args.get('next')

    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        #login the user...
        if session.get('next_url'):
            next_url = session.pop('next_url')        
            return redirect(next_url)
        else:
            # proceed as usual...
```

Comment: Thank you. This is working now. Is there any way to hide the `next_url` string? The URL `mysite.com/login?nexturl=............` can get pretty long and ugly.